# Java: Setting Quaternionf towards a specific position

Tags: java, quaternions, joml

I have a problem. I have created an object that will move in X, Y, Z axes in changing directions. I want to use the [Quaternionf](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Quaternionf.html) class as my tool. Knowing the X, Y, Z coordinates of the object and the coordinates of the target point, I want to set Quaternionf towards this point (from the position of the object, of course). The direction from the object point should always be towards the target point. I am attaching pictures showing what I mean.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the direction of the object is always facing the target. I will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no one unique rotation that faces the target, but you can use [`Quaternionf#lookAlong(Vector3fc, Vector3fc)`](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Quaternionf.html#lookAlong(org.joml.Vector3fc,org.joml.Vector3fc)), and for the `dir` parameter use `targetPos.sub(initialPos)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't quite understand how to use this method correctly and where and what arguments to give. Could I ask for more details?